# How to remove error: list index out of range for this specific code?

Tags: python, list

Basically, my code removes all duplicates that is next to eachother but for some reason i get error for empty list.
I would like to know what code should I add to remove the error when the list is empty?

My code works for list with integers like below for example:

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
    k2 = [a for a,b in zip(nums, nums[1:]+[not nums[-1]]) if a != b]
    return k2

remove_adjacent([1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]) == [1, 2, 3]
```

AS you can see it works but when I have an empty list I get this error:

```
 remove_adjacent([]) == list index out of range
```

What code should i add to fix this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check first using **if** statement if the list argument is empty, then return an empty list (or any text depends on the description of the problem) if it is.

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
    if len(nums) == 0: 
        return []   
    k2 = [a for a,b in zip(nums, nums[1:]+[not nums[-1]]) if a != b]
    return k2
```

Another approach to check if list is empty:

```
if not nums:
    return []
```

Or return string based on the given condition of the problem

You can also try using **try-except** block to catch the IndexError in case the given list is empty.

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
    try:
        k2 = [a for a,b in zip(nums, nums[1:]+[not nums[-1]]) if a != b]
    except IndexError:
        k2 = "The list is empty"
    return k2
```